# Speeding up nested loop equation in Mathematica

Tags: performance, loops, wolfram-mathematica

So I'm generating a genetic drift model investigating the change in the variables `{pab,pAb,paB,pAB}` using the recursion equation

```html
Psel[{pab_, pAb_, paB_, pAB_},s_] := 
   ({pab, pAb, paB, pAB} {1, 1 + s, 1 + s, (1 + s)^2})
   /(1 + s pAb + s paB + (2 s + s^2) pAB)
Pdrift[{pab_, pAb_, paB_, pAB_}, Npop_] := 
  If[Npop == Infinity, {pab, pAb, paB, pAB},
   RandomVariate[MultinomialDistribution[Npop, {pab, pAb, paB, pAB}]]
  /N[Npop]];
DriftEquation[{pab_, pAb_, paB_, pAB_}, s_, Npop_] := 
  Pdrift[Psel[{pab, pAb, paB, pAB}, s], Npop];
```

This is then run in a `For` loop `tmax`times. This loop is then repeated `reps` times using a `Do` loop. Imputed altogether into the function

```html
SimulateReps[s_, Npop_, tmax_, pint_, reps_] :=
  
  Module[{i, pqs, pqsrun, t, DriftEquS},
   pqs = {};
   DriftEquS[{pab_, pAb_, paB_, pAB_}] = 
    Simplify[DriftEquation[{pab, pAb, paB, pAB}, s, Npop]];
   Do[pqsrun = Table[{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {tmax}];
    pqsrun[[1]] = pint;
    For[t = 1, t < tmax, t++, 
     pqsrun[[t + 1]] = DriftEquS[pqsrun[[t]]]];
    pqs = Append[pqs, pqsrun];, {reps}];
   Return[pqs];
   ];

 pqs = SimulateReps[0.001, 10000, 1000, {0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25},10];
```

With `pqs` being the final result.

This works fine, except it takes ~15.982986 seconds to run, and I need to run nine variations of the function. Is their any way of speeding up the loops?

I've read that [compiling the code might work](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/07/10-tips-for-writing-fast-mathematica-code/), but I'm not sure how to use `Compile` function. Also I've tried `Reap` and `Sow` instead of `Append`, but I couldn't get it to work.

I'm still new to coding so any basic tips would be appreciated.

ps: there is an error message after running`pqs = SimulateReps[0.001, 10000, 1000,{0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25},10];`, but it doesn't seem to effect the results.

Comment: To use Reap: SimulateReps[...]:=Module[{...}, DriftEquS[{...}]=...; Reap[ Do[pqsrun = Table[{{0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0}}, {tmax}]; pqsrun[[1]] = pint; For[t = 1, t < tmax, t++, pqsrun[[t + 1]] = DriftEquS[pqsrun[[t]]] ]; Sow[pqsrun], {reps}]][[2, 1]]]; But that doesn't help enough. Perhaps you could use FoldList instead of For. Experiment with simpler examples of that until you see how to replace your For with that. You don't need to use Return[ ], the last expression is returned by default.

Comment: Mistake, NestList, not FoldList, perhaps something like this: SimulateReps[...] := Module[{...}, DriftEquS[{...}] = ...; Table[NestList[ DriftEquS, pint, tmax - 1], {reps}] ] but I'm not sure I have replicated your code correctly. The dimensions of the result match, but I can't use yourResult == myResult to verify mine is correct.

Comment: I tried the two approaches you suggest. They both work, but they only speed the code up by a few seconds.

Comment: The reason the results aren't equal might be because DriftEquS contains RandomVariate[MultinomialDistribution[...]], therefore all results should be slightly different.

Comment: Classic MMA folklore: Do, For, [[]], Append and lots of little individual steps are slower, turning something into a single internal function is usually faster. I did that and saw it wasn't substantially faster. Simplify can be slow, but when I eliminated that it didn't help either. Usually I try to compare outputs so I can be more confident that I haven't made any mistakes. I saw you had a random element but ran out of time to test. Now by resetting SeedRandom I see your output and mine are equal so I don't think I broke anything. Sorry I couldn't speed it up for you. Get 10x faster computer?

Comment: The reason you get the error messages might be that your t0 state doesn't satisfy the conditions for a multinomial. If you made your t0 state also a multinomial then I think that error message would go away. Reading the error message and trying to guess what it means might help explain this.

Comment: Thank you that helps a lot. Although It isn't much quicker, it still makes that   code more compact and easier to read.